# Beam deflection and p

Tags: python

This is the code I use to calculate deflection for a beam using the root function. It should calculate the maximum deflection point and plot the maximum the deflection point. I get this message when I run it:

> 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sp
from sympy import *

P = 2.5;
E = 50000;
I = 30000;
L = 600;

x = np.linspace(0,600)
V = (P/(120*E*I*L))*(np.power(x,5) + 2*np.power(600,2)*np.power(x,3)- 
x*np.power(600,4)) 
dVdx = 5*np.power(x,4) - 2160000*np.power(x,2) + 1.296e11
root =([dVdx,300])    
print(root,V(root))


x = np.linspace(0,600);
plt.plot(x,V(x),'LineWidth',2)
plt.plot(root,V(root),"*")   
plt.xlabel("x [cm]");
plt.ylabel("V(x) [cm]")
plt.title("Elastic Curve")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
print(root,V(root))
```

You are calling `V` like it is a function with the parameter `root`: `V(root)`.  `V` is an array, not a callable object.